# Manage XML configuration files

Tags: xml, version-control, config, ignore

I have a bunch of machines that have one XML file which holds the configuration. There are several nodes in the config file that are specific to each machine. Now I'm looking for a way to have a master config file which I can compare with the file on a machine. My first thought was using git, but I was not able to find a way to ignore specific lines within a file.

Comment: Looks like you are digging a big hole to throw yourself in, there mate. Hierarchy of configuration files was my first thought.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not the creator of that config structure. Furthermore i can not change anything on the structure (move the machine specific parts into a separate file for example) because the file gets read by a proprietary system.

Comment: Been there mate. Going to have to write something then I think. What are you checking for and why?

Comment: Its the configuration for a cnc controller and we need to check if the configuration is ok and up to date. I think i'm going to write some little utility using pythons [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)!